# ¿Cómo puedo crear un volumen nombrado en docker en un folder específico?

Tags: docker

Usando el comando:

```
docer volume create
```

Quiero crear el volumen en un foder específico ejemplo ~/data.

Answer (score 0):

Para **crearlo** se debe usar el parámetro bind así.

```
docker volume create --opt type=ext4 --opt device=/home/ubuntu/data/ --opt o=bind vol_nombre
```

Para probarlo se peude usar:

```
docker run -it -v vol_nombre:/tmp ubuntu bash
```

Una vez dentro de la shell usar el comando

```
touch /tmp/prueba
```

Luego listar los archivos en el hosts usando

```
ls ~/data
```

Para mas información del uso de volumenes visita: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/